# one element has two tooltip, conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I am working around `jquery tooltip` and I met an issue that when mouseover the element, the tooltip is not showing up.

I have a `<div class='test'>` and I use some plot tool (like highcharts) to plot some bars on this `<div>` element.

Then I put the code:

```
 $('.test').tooltip({
                    content: 'this is tooltip',
                    position: { my: 'center', at: 'center' }
                });
```

This is not working as expected.

I added another `<div>` just above this element, but without any plotting on this element, the tooltip works.

I am not sure why I have such an issue. My thoughts are either some other tooltip in highchart overrides this one or I have some conflicts.

Does someone who have the same experience give me some hints about this?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is use the `debugger tool` of `chrome` and compare the source code rendered by your browser on:

- **the div that has the chart**
- **the div that doesn't have the chart**

at the end of this you will exactly know what is messing the toltip on the DOM structure.

**How To**

- **right click**
- **inspect element**

try and provide a snipet of the dom to have me debugging it for you.

Regards